# Argument passed to Perl VERSION subroutine during module version check

Tags: perl

I define a Perl module, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package Sample;
use Data::Dumper; 
our $VERSION = v1.10;

sub VERSION
{
    my ($class, $version) = @_;
    print ("version is $version\n");
    print Dumper ($version);
}
```

The nature of the value passed in `$version` changes depending on how the module is imported:

```
$ perl -e 'use Sample 1.0'
version is 1
$VAR1 = '1';
```

However, if the required module version is specified as a v-string:

```
$ perl -e 'use Sample v1.0'
version is 
$VAR1 = v1.0;
```

What data type is being passed in `$version` in the second case? It's apparently not a simple scalar, and it's not a reference.

Comment: Please be careful overriding UNIVERSAL methods like VERSION. ([docs](https://perldoc.pl/UNIVERSAL)) In this case, you have broken version checks on this module, because they are run like: `Sample->VERSION($required_version)` and it is expected to return the version, or throw an exception if a version is passed and it's greater than the module's version. And since the version can be many things other than numbers, as you discovered, this is not a simple thing to reimplement. Further reading: http://blogs.perl.org/users/grinnz/2018/04/a-guide-to-versions-in-perl.html

Comment: If you just want to "intercept" versions that are passed to this method but not affect its normal functionality, try 'before' or 'after' from [Class::Method::Modifiers](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Method::Modifiers).

Comment: The example provided was stripped down to show the just the behavior in question. Your blog post was very helpful, thanks for that. I'll have a look at Class::Method::Modifiers, but our requirements (for an in-house system, not intended for public consumption) are such that normal VERSION behavior is not adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each dot-separated number is converted into a character with the ordinal value of the number.<sup>[1]</sup> In other words,

```
v1.0   ≡   "\x01\x00"   ≡   chr(1).chr(0)   ≡   pack('W*', 1, 0)
```

You can convert a v-string into something human readable using the `%vd` format specifier of `sprintf`.<sup>[2]</sup>

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say sprintf("%vd", v1.0)'
1.0
```

But it's better to use the [version](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?version) module.

```
$ perl -Mversion -e'CORE::say version->parse(v1.0)'
v1.0
```

It's better because the version module can handle version strings in general (not just v-strings).

```
$ perl -Mversion -e'
   my $v1 = version->parse(1.0);
   my $v2 = version->parse("1.0");
   my $v3 = version->parse(v1.0);
   my $v4 = version->parse("v1.0");
   CORE::say "equal"
      if $v1 == $v2
      && $v1 == $v3
      && $v1 == $v4
'
equal
```

One can use any numerical or string comparison operator<sup>[3]</sup> to compare version objects.

---

1. It's more than that, though. A scalar containing a v-string has magic (of type `V`) applied, so it's possible to dectect that it's a v-string.

   ```
   $ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump("\x01\x00"); Dump(v1.0);'
   SV = PV(0xbc9d70) at 0xbe7998
     REFCNT = 1
     FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,READONLY,PROTECT,pPOK)
     PV = 0xbf1ed0 "\1\0"\0
     CUR = 2
     LEN = 10
     COW_REFCNT = 0
   SV = PVMG(0xc20480) at 0xbe7938
     REFCNT = 1
     FLAGS = (RMG,POK,IsCOW,READONLY,PROTECT,pPOK)
     IV = 0
     NV = 0
     PV = 0xbf0190 "\1\0"\0
     CUR = 2
     LEN = 10
     COW_REFCNT = 0
     MAGIC = 0xbf3a80
       MG_VIRTUAL = 0
       MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_vstring(V)
       MG_LEN = 4
       MG_PTR = 0xbf1700 "v1.0"
   ```

   This magic is even applied to any scalar to which the v-string is copied!

   ```
   $ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'my $v1 = v1.0; my $v2 = $v1; Dump($v2)'
   SV = PVMG(0x9dc500) at 0x9a3a00
     REFCNT = 1
     FLAGS = (RMG,POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
     IV = 0
     NV = 0
     PV = 0x9ac1b0 "\1\0"\0
     CUR = 2
     LEN = 10
     COW_REFCNT = 2
     MAGIC = 0x9b8090
       MG_VIRTUAL = 0
       MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_vstring(V)
       MG_LEN = 4
       MG_PTR = 0x9adef0 "v1.0"
   ```

   I believe the version module takes advantage of this information.
2. This format specifier works on any string, so it's convenient for checking for hidden or special characters when debugging.

   ```
   $ perl -e'CORE::say sprintf "%v02X", "abc\r\n"'
   61.62.63.0D.0A
   ```
3. `==`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `<=>`, `eq`, `lt`, `gt`, `le`, `ge` and `cmp`.

Answer (score 2):

A v string is a string. Each number is assumed to be a Unicode code point and is converted to that character so what you are actually printing out is chr(1) . chr(0). You can prove this with the following script

```
my $vstring = v80.101.114.108
print $vstring, "\n";
```

This will print `Perl`